# Using snprintf to fill struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, printf

can someone tell me why variables in struct are overwriting?

output is:

```
Buffor is: 1.name , struct is: 1.name
Buffor is: 2.name , struct is: 2.name
Buffor is: 3.name , struct is: 3.name
3.name
3.name
3.name
```

```
    int i = 1;
    char buffor[100];
    int n = 3;

    struct person * data;
    data = (struct person *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct person));

    while (i <= n) {
        snprintf(buffor, sizeof(buffor), "%d.name", i);
        data[i - 1].firstname =buffor;
        printf("Buffor is: %s , struct is: %s \n", buffor, data[i - 1].firstname);
        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s \n", data[i].firstname);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To know how `struct person` actually is defined might help.

Comment: Could it be `firstname` is just a dump pointer?

Comment: Also this looks more like C, not like C++. Please decide, those are two different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `firstname` property of every single struct. Copying strings will just copy the pointer. Instead of

```
data[i - 1].firstname = buffor;
```

you need something like this:

```
data[i - 1].firstname = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffor) + 1);
strcpy(data[i - 1].firstname, buffor);
```

Comment: "*You need to allocate memory for every single struct*" in fact the OP did exactly this. ;-)

Comment: @alk. Ok, that was typo. Corrected :-)